# not a correct time display in gnuplot

Tags: time, gnuplot, axis-labels

I just started gnuplot and I have a problem with using "time" as x-variable. I have tried a lot of things but I cannot get it right.
My data looks like

```
# 
10-05-2013 1-52-56, 425,"lvl"  
10-05-2013 1-52-57, 425,"lvl"  
10-05-2013 1-52-58, 433,"lvl"  
10-05-2013 1-52-59, 433,"lvl"
```

I want to plot the values (425 etc) as y and the date/time as x (this date/time example uses a date starting with 1 (e.g. 1 AM) instead of 01 but the same problem occurs it the time is e.g. 19 hours). So 1-52-56 means 1 hour, 52 minutes and 56 seconds.

This is part of the script I use (the dataset is build "on the fly"):

---

```
# maak een lege plot zodat je verderop replot kunt gebruiken
load "gnuvars.txt"
set xrange [0:1]
set yrange [0:1]
set xtics rotate
set xtics font "0,9"
#set terminal wxt size 1000,700
#set terminal windows size 1150,830
set terminal windows size 1150,500
set terminal windows position 1,1
plot 1/0 notitle 
# zet eerst een lege commentaarregel in ylsecout.txt
# in deze file komen de uiteindel te plotten waarden te staan
system ("echo # > d:\\curl\\ylsecout.txt")
# maak een loopje over een (nu nog van tevoren bepaald) aantal iteraties
do for [i=0:nr_its]{
    #
    #lees na een aantal seconden de youless 1x uit en zet dat in het bestand ylsec.txt
    system ("timeout /T 1")
    system ("d:\\curl\\curl -c d:\\curl\\cookie.txt 192.168.178.14/L?w=password") 
    system ("d:\\curl\\curl -b d:\\curl\\cookie.txt 192.168.178.14/a?f=j -s -S >  d:\\curl\\ylsec.txt")
    #system ("echo. \>\>d:\\curl\\ylsec.txt")
    #lees datum, tijd uit en maak een plotbare datafile ylsecout.txt
    system ("call d:\\curl\\maakplotdata")
    # en maak een replot
    set title 'Meetwaarden Youless versus tijd'
    #set xlabel 'Time/s'
    #set ylabel 'waarden'
    set grid xtics
    set autoscale
    set xdata time
    set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S"
    set datafile separator ","
    replot 'ylsecout.txt' using 1:2 notitle with lines lw 3 lt rgb "red"
}
```

---

I incoprorated the entire code because perhaps I wrote something on beforehand that messes up the graph, but I assume the problem lies within:

```
set xdata time
set timefmt "%d-%m-%Y %H-%M-%S"
```

the plot I get only uses labels that incorporate the minutes and seconds, but not the hours or even the date. I can not get it right. Could somebody please look at it and tell me waht I am doing wrong?

thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

> the plot I get only uses labels that incorporate the minutes and
>   seconds, but not the hours or even the date.

The format of the xtic labels can be changed with `set format x '<format>'`, e.g. to include date and hours use:

```
set format x '%d/%m - %H:%M:%S'
```

These will be quite long and perhaps you would also want better room for them:

```
set xtics rotate by -45
```

See `help time/date` for more.

Comment: the set format command did the trick. Thanks! It really took me hours since a very comparable script runs oke. The problem was that it the date was not included in the x, the plot started all over again if the time ran over 23:59.. Now it is (almost, but I can adjust that) as I want it to. The range is only for the fist plot (which is not a plot but merely to get replot working) and is overruled by the atuoscale I use later. The scale is adjusted to the correct dates and times when I use the replot. Thanks tremendously for your help. is is very much appreciated!

Comment: I can not vote up, since my "reputation" value is not high enough yet. I can accept the answer as a correct one, though, and I just did. Sorry that I can not vote it up